# How to set $(this) to a variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

first of all, im a starter when it comes to programming.

I'm trying to make a little game, and want to do it with jquery(thinking about getting back to JS). But i came to a problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("div").click(function(){
  selected = $(this);
  // just a debug, giving the following answer:X Axis : undefined Y Axis :       undefined
 $("#demo").html("X Axis : " + selected.pageX + " Y Axis : " + selected.pageY);
 ;
 });    
//moves selected div to current mouse location on click

  $(document).click(function(e){
     selected.css({position:"absolute", top:e.pageY, left: e.pageX});
  });


   });
```

as soon as i click on a div, i want to make it 'selected'  so i can make it go to the location of the mouse when i click in the document. But only the selected div has to go there. Best idea i could think of was with using a variable but how do i properly set the 'this' div to the variable.

EDIT:here is a short explanation of the complete setup, it will be a game, where you will control units to battle each other, this will be viewed from above. So lets say we click on a unit, they need to be 'selected' and then, when we click on the document, the selected unit needs to move there

**edit:SOLVED, thanks for the help!**

Comment: Two things: #1) - should be `var selected = $(this)`.  #2) Check out jQuery documentation for [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: Do you mean you want to drag and drop the DIV? Take a look at the Draggable and Droppable widgets in jQuery UI.

Comment: its not really drag and drop, in time, it will be units which will have to walk to the clicked position

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking the question I *think* you are asking...

"How do I determine which div the user clicked on"

Then you'll want to look at jQuery's [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method with the delegate syntax.

```
$(document).on("click", "div", function(){
   selected = $(this);
   // Or use jQuery's methods to get these values.       
   // Either way your syntax was trying to be a mix of both.
   $("#demo").html("X Axis : " + this.pageX + " Y Axis : " + this.pageY);
 });
```

Comment: i think i have thatw ith the following code                                                                    $('div').click(function(){
     $(this).css({position:"absolute", top:e.pageY, left: e.pageX});
  });

Comment: @user3133403 -- You're welcome.   Just a friendly reminder, since your new to StackOverflow -- If my answer was useful don't forget to upvote or accept it.

Comment: i am new indeed, but unfortunately my problem isnt solved. selected says it is still empty, so it doesnt contain te data ov the div where i clicked on

Comment: can you post that code also , where you are using the value of selected

Comment: many thanks, do not know where i went wrong, i update the code, but it works. you can check my current code in my question again. There is only one thing left, when i click the div, it also move at the same click because of the 2 function starting at the same time, is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: No need to have two event handlers.  You can easily combine the two of them.

Answer (score 0):

it should be more like this, to get the `current coordinates of the mouse` pointer , `when the div was clicked`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").click(function(event){
     selected = $(this);
     $("#demo").html("X Axis : " + event.pageX + " Y Axis : " + event.pageY);
     ;
  });
```

EDIT: based on your comments, see this

http://jsfiddle.net/72x5A/

Comment: thanks for your answer, i think i got my question asked wrong, anyways, i had this code and it prints the current location of the click right?, but the main question is to get the div where i clicked on into a variable so i can do something with that specific div later on

Comment: @user3133403 ok, for that you can use a global variable , remove the var, now the variable will be visible outside.see the edit. your method of storing it correct. now when you move to the new position, you would just change the coordinates of the selecte div

Comment: for changing the coordinates set top= mouse pointer Y and left=mouse pointer X in style for that particular div. i recommend you position the divs absolute

Answer (score 0):

I would give every div you want to be "moveable" a class, "moveable".

```
$(function () {

    var $moveables = $('.moveable');

    $moveables.click(function () {
        $moveables.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $('body').click(function (e) {
        $('.selected').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: e.pageY,
            left: e.pageX
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Define selected outside the function in order to make the variable global.

```
    var selected; 
$("div").click(function(){
  selected = $(this);
  // just a debug, giving the following answer:X Axis : undefined Y Axis :       undefined
 $("#demo").html("X Axis : " + selected.pageX + " Y Axis : " + selected.pageY);
 ;
 });
```

Then it works as is :)
Check it out ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/6nmKY/4/

Comment: This is exactly the same. Defining "selected" within the callback without "var" declares it globally as a property on window, which is exactly what "var selected;" does when defined in global namespace.